# How can I attach a select dropdown to a text box?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to attach a `select` dropdown to a search box. So far, I kind of got it working on larger monitors:

[image: search box]

However, the problem is, when I resize my browser window to < 1100px width, the "Everything" gets cut off:

[image: search text cut off]

I tried applying a `min-width` of e.g. 150px to the dropdown but it doesn't seem to be having any effect. Adding a `min-width` to the container works, but when I resize the window, the controls break to the next line. I'm guessing that the approach I took (using a nested 12-column grid with no gutters to align the dropdown, text box, and button) isn't the right way to do this.

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/jh2fgmo7/

How can I attach the select dropdown to the text box but keep a minimum width equivalent to the select box's largest value (using CSS only)?

### Update-

This is the desired result when resizing:

[image: search bar desired result]

## CSS

```
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  font: normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva;
}
body:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.tbnav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: #303030;
  min-height: 55px;
}
.tbnav .logo {
  width: 11.39241%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.26582%;
  margin-left: 3.16456%;
  background: url(/images/tb-logo.gif) no-repeat;
  height: 27px;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin-top: 14px;
}
.tbnav .search {
  width: 62.02532%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.26582%;
}
.tbnav .search .searchcat {
  width: 11.01695%;
  float: left;
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: 11.5px;
}
.tbnav .search .searchcat select {
  height: 33px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.tbnav .search .searchbox {
  width: 78.81356%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 27px;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 11.5px;
}
.tbnav .search .searchbtn {
  width: 6.77966%;
  float: left;
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: 11.5px;
}
.tbnav .search .searchbtn input {
  height: 33px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tbnav">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="search">
            <div class="searchcat">
                <select name="c">
                    <option>Everything</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="search" class="searchbox" />
            <div class="searchbtn">
                <input type="submit" class="button button-primary button-small" value="Go" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a `min-width` on the `.search` class?

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass or Susy?  This is a pure CSS problem.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough here.  You have a pure CSS problem, and you've provided your "attempts" in a language+library most CSS experts do not use.  Changing your question to exclude the words Sass and Susy do not change this.

Comment: @KevinBoucher - Yes, and that works, but prevents the box from resizing fully (updated question with a desired result image).

Comment: @cimmanon - Originally, I indicated it for 3 reasons: 1) If there was a way to solve the issue using a mixin or breakpoint, I'd prefer that solution over vanilla CSS. 2) Whether most CSS experts use or do not use a library is irrelevant. 3) Since I am using Sass/Susy to position and scale the text box and dropdown, I figured it was relevant to mention it.

Comment: Yeah, you tagged it correctly. Your original code included those libraries and it was appropriate to tag them. It doesn't matter if "experts do not use" it (which is total BS anyways... experts use whatever makes their job easier). Cimmanon just has a filter preference set for Sass and hates it when people clog up his feed with questions he doesn't care to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would do `.searchcat { position: absolute; }`, set it to the desired width, then set `.searchbox { padding-left: /*whatever*/; }`. As a quick fix. You might throw some Javascript in there if the `<select>` contents will be variable (i.e. loaded dynamically) just to check what the widest value is.

Comment: I had problems with `.searchcat` overlapping (or moving beyond the screen) on mobile, but the approach worked excellently on larger monitors. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, I used a basic table and styled it with CSS instead. It works just how I wanted now. Hope this helps someone! (If anyone wants the underlying Sass script, let me know!)

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dzoppzzL/

### CSS

```
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  font: normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva;
}
body:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.tbnav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: #303030;
  min-height: 65px;
}
.tbnav .logo {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.26582%;
  margin-left: 3.16456%;
  background: url(/images/tb-logo.gif) no-repeat;
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.tbnav .search {
  margin-top: 13px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: 3.16456%;
  width: 62.02532%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.26582%;
}
.tbnav .search .searchcat {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.tbnav .search .searchcat select {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  height: 39px;
  width: 150px;
  color: #808080;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tbnav .search .searchtxt {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.tbnav .search .searchtxt .searchbox {
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tbnav .search .searchbtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.tbnav .search .searchbtn input {
  height: 39px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

### HTML

```
        <table class="search">
            <tr>
                <td class="searchcat">
                    <select name="c" id="catsel">
                        <option>Everything</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="searchtxt">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="searchbox" />
                </td>
                <td class="searchbtn">
                    <input type="submit" class="button button-primary button-small" value="Go" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```